# Ruby on Rails: how do I convert this date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`Wed Sep 22 13:15:02 -0400 2010` to this format `2010-08-23 13:15:02 -0400`

The left is Time.now

The right is 30.days.ago =\

Comment: So... what's your question? You just want it output in the format on the right?

Comment: yes, cause the format on the right is the format that MySQL uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `to_s(:db)` method in Time class to convert it to a database-friendly format.

```
Time.now.to_s(:db) # => "2010-09-22 17:50:41"
```

If you really need the time zone offset info, you could add a custom format to `Time::DATE_FORMATS`, e.g.

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:db_with_zone_offset] = lambda { |time|
  time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S #{time.formatted_offset(false)}")
}
```

after which you can simply call

```
Time.now.to_s(:db_with_zone_offset) => # "2010-09-22 17:48:21 +0000"
```

Comment: I added the custom format (which uses Time#formatted_offset), because as far as I know there is no formatting option in strftime to display the time zone offset (the '+0000'). Rails uses a [similar strategy](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html) in the built-in formatting types. (See especially DATE_FORMATS[:rfc2822])

Answer (score 1):

Both are different data types.

```
>> Time.now.class
=> Time
>> 30.days.ago.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

use the strftime method to format it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have format in database format, then you can use:

```
Time.now
=> Wed Sep 22 19:54:24 +0200 2010
Time.now.to_s(:db)
=> "2010-09-22 19:54:48"
Time.now.utc.to_s(:db)
=> "2010-09-22 17:55:16"
```